# Media Recorder record application audio

Tags: android, audio, record, soundpool, mediarecorder

I have an application that has a few buttons that have sounds (`soundPool`) I need to write them down on a flash card I make it through the `MediaRecorder` but when I run the app and then turn on the record playing and click stop recording application crashes you do not tell me what the problem is?
I expect that in the method `recordStop`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    int kickSound;
    SoundPool mSoundPool;
    AssetManager assets;

  private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
  private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
  private String fileName;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    assets = getAssets();

    kickSound = loadSound("snare_trap.ogg");

    ImageButton kick = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    kick.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                playSound(kickSound);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/record.3gpp";
  }

  protected void playSound(int sound) {

        if (sound > 0)
          mSoundPool.play(sound, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
      }


      private int loadSound(String fileName) {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
            try {
              afd = assets.openFd(fileName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't load file '" + fileName + "'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return -1;
            }
            return mSoundPool.load(afd, 1);
          }


  public void recordStart(View v) {
    try {
      releaseRecorder();

      File outFile = new File(fileName);
      if (outFile.exists()) {
        outFile.delete();
      }

      mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
      mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
      mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
      mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
      mediaRecorder.prepare();
      mediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  public void recordStop(View v) {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
    }


  public void playStart(View v) {
    try {
      releasePlayer();
      mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
      mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileName);
      mediaPlayer.prepare();
      mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void playStop(View v) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
      mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
  }

  private void releaseRecorder() {
    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
      mediaRecorder.release();
      mediaRecorder = null;
    }
  }

  private void releasePlayer() {

      mediaPlayer.release();
      mediaPlayer = null;
    }


  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releasePlayer();
    releaseRecorder();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you releasing the recorder to start out with?  Releasing should only be used if you don't want to access the recorder anymore.  Try moving the release to the end.